# What would be the maximum value of PHP rand() function , if we provide no parameters to it ??

Tags: php, random

I want to know what maximum value and minimum value PHP rand() function returns if we don't provide any parameter like min and max 
e.g.

```
//what will be maximum and minimum output of this      
echo rand();
```

Comment: Why are you using `rand()` over `mt_rand()` or `random_int()` (php7)?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Note that `rand()` uses `mt_rand()` implicitly in v7.1+.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we give no arguments to `rand()` function, random number can be generated between `0` and `getrandmax()` as per the PHP documentation.

`grandmax()` function always takes the maximum number depends upon your operating system such as Windows where the maximum number is 32767 that can be generated.

So its clear from this, In **Windows** when we run **rand()** function without arguments:

> Minimum Number that can be generated is 0
>
> Maximum Number that can be generated is 32767

Below links can help further to know rand() function but there is no documentation regarding maximum number generated in Mac or other Operating Systems:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php

https://www.w3resource.com/php/function-reference/rand.php

https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_math_rand.asp

Answer (score 1):

The minimal value of `rand()` without arguments is `0`.

The maximum value is platform dependent, but you can use [`getrandmax()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getrandmax.php) to see the largest possible random value on your machine.